# Cannot make tftp connection for PIX firewall password reset

Tags: networking, cisco

I am trying to reset my firewall password so that I can do a factory reset on it.

I bought it used and the rules are more restrictive than I want. It's being used for a small project where we can demonstrate a bad configuration.

I am following the Cisco [PIX Password Recovery Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_password_recovery09186a008009478b.shtml) as the basis for my procedure.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. Turn off wireless
2. Go to my LAN network options and click on ipv4 options
3. Set the ip 192.168.1.49 and DNS 255.255.255.255, click ok
4. Start a tftp server on the ip 192.168.1.49
5. Connect the firewall via ETHERNET to my laptop (I also have the console serial connected)
6. Go into my terminal and type address 192.168.1.75, this is the ip I want for the firewall
7. Then I type server 192.168.1.49, ip of my comp/server
8. I use the command ping 192.168.1.75 to test the connection and it says 0/5 successful
9. I tried using the tftp command to get the file I needed, but it just hung forever

What could I be doing wrong?

I checked out wireshark to see what was happening with the 'tftp' command and it would always say port unreachable. I am using port 69 on my tftp server, if the ping command didn't work the tftp command probably isn't going to work either

The firewall is connected DIRECTLY to laptop via ETHERNET. I tried using interface 0, but it failed.  Interface 1 worked just fine. I don't know if this makes a difference or not.

I am going to try to put a router in between the two to see if it will help me at all

Comment: This could be windows firewall blocking the connections

Comment: While this is about a device that provides security-related functions on a network, I'm not seeing a question that's actually about security here.  Maybe [sf] might be a better place for this.  I've flagged it for migration - please don't cross-post.

Comment: This is more about device configuration, albeit a traditionally security device. This is really a better fit for our sister site for Information Technology Professionals, [SF].

Answer (score 1):

I've only worked on the ASA series firewalls and this is the procedure I use: http://www.ranjodh.com/cisco/how-to-reset-asa-password/. I believe it will work on the PIX as well.

Either way you can always call the TAC and they will walk you threw it step by step.

Comment: I'm trying to use 192.168.1.* 255.255.255.255, should it be 255.255.255.0 or do I need to use a router and switch?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a switch between your computer and the firewall, but a direct connection should work.

You need to change the IP address of your computer to 192.168.1.* 255.255.255.0.  This could definitely cause the issues you described.  By specifying 255.255.255.255 as the netmask, you told the computer that the entire network consists of only 1 IP address.  Even if it successfully receives tftp traffic from the PIX, your computer won't know how to respond since there are no other devices on your interface's network.

Also, be sure to turn off, or properly configure your desktop firewall.

You would probably get more feedback for this question on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com